# Get names and path of generated documents

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need some help with a specific problem. Maybe someone can help me.

So my source file is an XML document. With the help of my xslt-stylesheet certain elements of the XML files are used to create new output files (result-document). Here is my code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" version="2.0" >
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<xsl:output indent="yes"
    doctype-public="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" method="xml"/>



<xsl:template match="name1">

    <xsl:variable name="name" select="concat('aus/',@xml:id,'/',@xml:id)"/>


            <xsl:result-document href="{$name}.collectione" indent="yes">

                        <element>

                                <xsl:attribute name="attributeName" select="???"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                        </element>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>


            </xsl:result-document>

            <xsl:result-document href="{$name}.collectione.meta" indent="yes">
            </xsl:result-document>

            <xsl:apply-templates/>
```

(...)

Now that the files are created I want to display a list of all created files being an "element"s "attributeName"s value including like 2 previous parentfolders. It should look like this:

```
<element attributeName="../aus/tg1/tg1.collectione"/>
    <element attributeName="../aus/tg1/tg1.collectione.meta"/>
    <element attributeName="../aus/tg2/tg2.collectione"/>
```

Can anyone help me?

PS: Is there a way to display files from certain folders?

**EDIT**

thanks for your help.

Tony, this seems to work. Yet it would only display only ".collectione". I want to display all created documents (about 300). They have different names like ".collectione", "blabla.aggregation", "bla.aggration.item" etc.

These documents are also in different folders, like:

```
aus/collectione
aus/collectione.meta
aus/te1/te1.aggregation
aus/te1/te1.aggregation.meta
aus/te2/te2.edition
aus/te2/te2.edition.meta
aus/te2/te2.work
(...)
```

What I want is basically a list within one of the result-Documents, that produces something like:

```
<element attributeName="aus/collectione"/>
<element attributeName="aus/collectione.meta"/>
<element attributeName="aus/te1/te1.aggregatione"/>
<element attributeName="aus/te1/te1.aggregatione.meta"/>
<element attributeName="aus/te2/te2.editione"/>
<element attributeName="aus/te2/te2.editione.meta"/>
```

(and so on)

One Xpath expression should catch a) all documents and b) another xpatch expression should catch me all documents of a specific folder.

So lets say, when I open the file "te1.aggregatione" I want to see all files written in te1-folder:

```
<element attributeName="aus/te1/te1.aggregatione"/>
<element attributeName="aus/te1/te1.aggregatione.meta"/>
```

However when I open the collectione file I want to have a list of all files (about 300).

I hope I expressed myself clearly this time o/

Comment: The code you have posted does not create hundreds of documents in a single run so it is not clear what you want to achieve. Also which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use? In the case of Saxon 9.5 you might want to check whether you can move to saxon 9.6 where the new `uri-collection` function might help to read out all URIs of files in a directory or folder.

Comment: It would also helped if you showed your input XML document (or at least a representative sample of it if it is large). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this...

```
<xsl:attribute name="attributeName" select="concat($name, '.collectione')"/>
```

Or maybe create a new variable, to use in two different places

```
<xsl:variable name="name" select="concat('aus/',@xml:id,'/',@xml:id)"/>
<xsl:variable name="fullname" select="concat($name, '.collectione')"/>
<xsl:result-document href="{$fullname}" indent="yes">
    <element>
       <xsl:attribute name="attributeName" select="$fullname"/>
```

Or better still, use an attribute value template instead of `xsl:attribute`

```
 <element attributeName="{$fullname}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Process the source again in a different mode (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#modes), e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  <list>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="list" />
  </list>
</xsl:apply-templates>

<xsl:template match="name1" mode="list">
  <element attributeName="aus/{@xml:id}/{@xml:id}.collectione" />
  <element attributeName="../aus/{@xml:id}/{@xml:id}.collectione.meta" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you Tony. Although I think I expressed myself unclear. I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Saxon, you can use query parameters to select (existing) files matching a pattern and recurse into subdirectories (http://saxonica.com/documentation/html/sourcedocs/collections.html).

```
collection('aus?select=*.collectione*;recurse=yes')
```

will return the document nodes of the files I think you are interested in.  You can then use `base-uri()` on each node to get its base URI.

Alternatively, if you have Saxon 9.6 or another XSLT 3.0 processor, you can do as Martin Honnen said and use `uri-collection()` (http://saxonica.com/documentation/html/functions/fn/uri-collection.html).

Once you have all the URIs, you could write them all out as your top-level file and also use `xsl:for-each-group` to group them by directory to get the file names to write out in the second-level files, and recursively do the same for lower levels if you want.

Comment: Heya, thanks Tony. This should work, but Oxygen gives me the "Premature end of file" Error, any clues?

Comment: Oxygen should also be able to show you where it thinks the problem is when you look at the file in Oxygen.  I can't help you without seeing at least the element in the stylesheet where you use `collection()`.